# powershell exchange : how do you setup a scheduled task to run exchange2007 powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, exchange-server-2007

I'm having trouble setting up a scheduled task (now called Task Scheduler) under the actions tab to run on windows 2007 server. It also has exchange server 2007.

I've tried setting

Program/script : C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Add arguments (optional): -psconsolefile exshell.psc1 -command "& {c:\mes-detail\emsbilling08.ps1}"
Start in (optional): "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Bin\

I realize the exshell.psc1 probably also needs an explicit path so I've also tried:

-psconsolefile C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Bin\exshell.psc1 -command "& {c:\mes-detail\mailall3.ps1}" as well but that doesn't work either

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured I'd share the resolution here to finish what is started.

> 1) In your .ps1 file put Add-PSSnapin
>   *exchange*
>
> 2) for the scheduled task, do this:
>   Program/script :
>   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
>   Add arguments (optional): -noprofile
>   -Noninteractive c:\mes-detail\emsbilling08.ps1 Start
>   in (optional): "C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Bin\

If it still doesn't work, run the following checks:

> Start...Run
>   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
>   -noprofile
>
> Get-PSSnapin -Registered
>
> Do you see
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Support
>
> If so, do add-pssnapin *exchange*

Answer (score 0):

What doesn't work? Have you tried running one of those commands manually, to see what happens?

(BTW: Suggestion, you may want to take this to the PowerShell forum at minasi.com/forum or powershelcommunity.org. You're likely to be asking a larger audience that's knowledgeable about the topic, since this is kinda borderline for StackOverflow's programmer-centric population).

Answer (score 0):

> PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> add-pssnapin exchange
>   Add-PSSnapin : Windows PowerShell snap-in exchange is not installed on the mach
>   ine.
>   At line:1 char:13
>   + add-pssnapin  <<<< exchange

Write full Name in your script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Support
```